Excel - Summing the product of multiple ranges if their sum of different permutations of their row# adds up to a target value
I have a messy Excel formula that I'm trying to figure out.  I have data with 2 or more columns, each associated with the probability (labeled p1, p2, p3, etc.) of a particular whole number outcome (marked by the column labeled "row#").  To find the final probability, the probability of the sum of the whole numbers coming up when all the scenarios are combined, I need the sum of the products of all of the probabilities where any combinations of the row# add up to a target value.
For example, in the image below, to find the probability of pFinal being 3, I need to multiply every combination of p1, p2 and p3 where their corresponding row# adds up to 3.
So where p1 is 3, p2 and p3 would both be 0.  So I would multiply the value of p1 at 3, p2 at 0 and p3 at 0.  But where p1 is 2, p2 could be 1 and p3 0, or p2 could be 0 and p3 could be 1.  So I would need to add in the product of those two trios as well.  To get the final value of pFinal at 3, I would add up there products:
pFinal =
p1-3 * p2-0 * p3-0  +
p1-2 * p2-1 * p3-0  +
p1-2 * p2-0 * p3-1  +
p1-1 * p2-2 * p3-0  +
p1-1 * p2-1 * p3-1  +
p1-1 * p2-0 * p3-2  +
p1-0 * p2-3 * p3-0  +
p1-0 * p2-2 * p3-1  +
p1-0 * p2-1 * p3-2  +
p1-0 * p2-0 * p3-3

row# 4 and higher wouldn't come into it for calculating pFinal at 3, since 4 > 3, but would be needed to calculate pFinal at 4.
I know excel has a bunch of functions for handling probabilities and combinations, not to mention SUMPRODUCT, but I'm not sure if there is a set of formulae that can handle this dynamically.
Excel Example
Thanks for any help on this!
( I did figure out how to do this with only p1 and p2, using INDIRECT, ADDRESS and SORTBY to manipulate the arrays/ranges, but as soon as I add in a p3, that solution goes out the window.)
=======================================================
Here's more info about what I'm actually trying to achieve.  Each column of the data comes from a binomial distribution representing the probability of a given number of successful outcomes.  Now I want to combine multiple different scenarios, adding up the successful outcomes from each, and calculate the probability of each total number of successes.
Here's an example of a similar but simplified scenario:
Let's say I roll 3 six-sided dice and count everything 4 or higher as a success (50% chance).  The distribution of successful results, calculable with BINOM.DIST, is:
0: 12.5%    1: 37.5%    2: 37.5%    3: 12.5%
Then I roll 2 more six-sided dice, this time counting only 5 and up as a success (33% chance).  This time the distribution is:
0: 44.4%    1: 44.4%    2: 11.1%    3: 0%
Now I want to combine the two runs by adding up the successes across both runs, which can range from 0 to 5 successes.  This can be achieved by multiplying the probabilities from all the combinations of scenarios that add up to the total number of successes.  For example, there are three (really two) ways to get 4 total successes:

3 successes in the first run and 1 in the second: 12.5% * 44.4% = 5.56%
2 successes in each run: 37.5% * 11.1% = 4.17%
1 success in the first run and 3 in the second: 37.5% * 0% = 0%

I can add up those results to get the final probability of 4 successes across both runs:
5.56 + 4.17% + 0.00% = 9.73%
But the number of runs needs to be flexible, and could be up to five different binomial distributions that are being combined.
Simple Example

I think it might help to say something about what is the bigger picture here. What is the problem that the spreadsheet needs to solve? Does it have something to do with the distribution of a sum of random variables?

I have updated my post with more details, as per your comment.

OK, great. The operation you need is called discrete convolution, and a web search seems to show there is an Excel function for that. Here's the result in another system (Octave) for the problem you showed: p1 = [1/2, 1/2]; p2 = [2/3, 1/3]; conv (conv (conv (p1, p1), p1), conv (p2, p2)) Working with the discrete convolution is at least 10 times simpler, you should really try to make use of that if at all possible. (Btw the reason it's relevant is that the distribution of a sum of random variables is the convolution of their distributions.)

Thanks!  I'll explore that and see where it takes me!

Robert Didier's comments are excellent but unfortunately there is no convolution function in Excel. You could make use of the BINOM.DIST.RANGE() function - for example, =BINOM.DIST.RANGE(3, 1/2, 2) returns 0.375 while =BINOM.DIST.RANGE(2, 1/3, 1) returns 0.444.... The COMBIN() function might also be useful. Doing this in pure Excel up to 5 runs is certainly possible, but will require a largeish worksheet - a single formula isn't realistic. If you need additional help with constructing the worksheet then please say.

For the record, a web search for "excel convolution function" brings up a few hits; the most promising one is this: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/convolution.1224007/ which gives VB code for a convolution function. I didn't try the code; the author gives three versions -- I gather the third one fixes problems with the other two.

Thanks!  Yeah, I realized that there wasn't a function for discreet convolution in Excel, and BINOM.DIST.RANGE() can't solve the convolution portion of the problem.  COMBIN() could work with a messy spreadsheet in little steps, but I needed this to be pretty plug and play fire a bunch of data.  I ended up solving in using VBA to create my own CONVOL() function, which takes in the various arrays to step through the problem.  It's working great.  Thanks everyone for your help!
